# How to NOT call onCreateOptionsMenu when calling FragmentManager.replace()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-menu, fragmenttransaction

I have a `Toolbar` being used as an `ActionBar` with two items. I only want to ever display one at a time as they kind of replace each other. The problem is that when i replace a `Fragment`, it call `onCreateOptionsMenu` and will inflate the menu again, meaning that the same action button will be shown, even if the other one was previously in the `ActionBar`. I have to need to change anything in the `ActionBar` from my `Fragments` or when a new `Fragment` is displayed(with `FragmentManager.FragmentTransaction.replace()`). So my question is how do I not call `onCreateOptionsMenu` when a new fragment is displayed?

I can't use a `boolean` because I will still need it to reinflate on orientation change. And any advice on how to handle orentation change for my situation?

I can post code, but it seems more conceptual and I'm not sure that it would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by instead of not calling `onCreateOptionsMenu`, I added the items to my menu manually.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean refreshVisible;

    if (refreshItem != null && refreshItem.isVisible()){//is being displayed prior to inflation
        refreshVisible = true;
    }else if (refreshItem == null){//it's null so the menu has never been created
        refreshVisible = true;
    }else {//it's not null and invisibe, other icon was being displayed
        refreshVisible = false;
    }

    menu.clear();//clear menu so there are no duplicate or overlapping icons
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);//inflate menu
    refreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh);
    useDataItem = menu.findItem(R.id.use_data);
    refreshItem.setVisible(refreshVisible);//if menu is being created for first time or item was previously visible, then display this item
    useDataItem.setVisible(!refreshVisible);//display this item if not displaying other

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would fiddle with the [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)) hook. If you can detect that your menu should not be shown you should jest return false from there. Per documentation:

> Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the contents.

and

> You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown.

Comment: I have done this where `onPrepareOptionsMenu` returns false and it doesn't call `onCreateOptionsMenu`, but `onCreateOptionsMenu` was called before it.

Comment: Yes because for the first time the onCreateOptionsMenu is called at the end of the onCreate method of an Activity. I am not sure whether it will work but try the approach that @OmarAlbelbaisy suggested.

Comment: No, I mean `onCreateOptionsMenu` is being called before on a new fragment transaction. I did do what he suggested. I don't think it helped. I solved my problem by manually inflating the `Menu`.

Comment: Interesting can you share the code of working solution?

Comment: Just did in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can call `setHasOptionsMenu(false);` inside your fragment.

This will prevent `onCreateOptionsMenu()` from being called when that fragment added.

Comment: I put that in all of my fragments and it was still being called, but I solved it by manually setting the items. See my answer

Comment: Actually, when I set it to false, `onCreateOptionsMenu()` wasn't being called in my fragment, but it was still being called in my activity every time a fragment transaction occurred.

Comment: Try to call menu.clear(); in your activity's onCreateOptionsMenu() to clear previous added items before inflating the menu.

Comment: If you look at my answer, you can see that I did exactly that

Comment: Sorry i didn't noticed that, I'm glad you solved your problem. +1